# How to prevent windows from starting unmounted drive?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multi-boot

I have a dualboot desktop computer with 2 SDDs and one HDD, one of the SDDs is for Windows 10, the other one for Debian Linux.

The HDD is used solely for Linux and all partitions are formatted for ext4. But Windows briefly starts this HDD at least once per hour.

Is there a way to prevent Windows from doing that?

Comment: I just did that.  Thank you for that hint, Robert.  However, only a test can reveal if it worked.  I will post a follow up.

Comment: Yep, your advice did the trick, Robert.  I can confirm that Windows now leaves the drives alone which it can't mount anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you don't mount any partitions of a disk the disk itself is still known to the disk management system of Windows and I would assume that Windows periodically polls the disk for changes (e.g. on the partition table) and thus the disk spins up.

You can avoid this by selecting the disk in the Device Manager and select `Disable device` from it's context menu.